# Save UICollectionViewCell as image using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell

I am using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext to capture the screen but image quality is not good. Could any one help me how to save UICollectionViewCell as high quality image and how to get the size of dynamic cell when cell is selected.

Comment: Show your code. How are you creating the context and drawing the cell? What do you want to do with the image? Could you use a snapshot view instead?

Comment: This question doesn't show any interest to solve the issue by yourself. Have you tried to do it? Any code? What problems did you face? SOF users are to help with problems not write code instead of you... Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

CollectionView delegate method would get u the cell when it is selected and the cell image would be saved into your project documents directory.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cell.bounds.size);

    [cell.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"New ImageFolder"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:stringPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:stringPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

    NSString *fileName = [stringPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/image.jpg"];
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 1.0);
    [data writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];

}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I am kind a new to ios programming so could not relate much on myself. But the code mentioned by is great help.